# How to update table set column = null where column = '\' without error of MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''\'' at line 1

Tags: mysql

How to update table set column = null where column = `\` in mysql?

I always got error of `1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''\'' at line 1`

Comment: Double the `\` to account for the sql context. Depending on your you are issuing this sql (e.g. language, shell), it may require more escaping. So please show the exact SQL and the language in which it is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You should use '\\' 


update students set firstname = null where firstname = '\\'
```

Comment:  How do you know this???? Could you please send me some tutorials or name of books about it , thanks so so so so much

Comment: backslash (\\) is known as the "escape character". You can read more are about it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html